# Sorting an an ArrayList of Objects in Java

Tags: java, sorting, object, arraylist

I have an object that holds an int value, a String, and a double. Instances of that object are stored in an ArrayList. I want to print that object now but I want to first sort the ArrayList by the String values. I am having a hard time conceptualizing how I'd do that through something like a selection sort. Any help would be grateful!

Here is what I thought you were suppose to do, but that didn't seem to work.

```
public static void sSortStrings(ArrayList<Student> list) { //Selection sort
     int count1;
     int count2;
     int largest;
     String temp;
     for (count1 = 0; count1 < list.size() - 1; count1++) {
      largest = 0;
      for (count2 = largest + 1; count2 < list.size() - count1; count2++) {
       if (list[largest].compareTo(list[count2]) < 0) {
        largest = count2;
       }
      }
      temp = list[list.size() - 1 - count1];
      list[list.size() - 1 - count1] = list[largest];
      list[largest] = temp;
     }
    }
```

Just to throw in there my professor had included this in the source code, but I'm not sure if I should be calling it instead of the compare to method

```
public boolean nameComesBefore(Student other) {
    return name.compareToIgnoreCase(other.name) < 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I think **Comparable** will suffice your need.you can visit this [link](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist-of-object-sort-example-comparable-and-comparator/) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `Student` class has getter for the String property. 
Then all you need to do to sort the list is
 `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getName))`

This will sort the given list by student's name. 
For more options check javadoc for [List.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) and [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).